# Bash: New line in echo string fails when output is piped to crontab

Tags: linux, bash, shell, cron

Bash: New line in `echo` string fails when output is piped to `crontab`.

The `\n` new line combo seems to be treated as part of the string, while it should be treated as a new line symbol.

---

Consider:

```
echo "0 0 * * * ~/cronDaily.sh \n 0 0 * * 0 ~/cronWeekly.sh" | crontab
```

The current state is the above command prints the following output into `crontab`:

`"0 0 * * * ~/cronDaily.sh \n 0 0 * * 0 ~/cronWeekly.sh`

The desired state is a command that would print this to crontab:
    0 0 * * * ~/cronDaily.sh
    0 0 * * 0 ~/cronWeekly.sh

---

The above problem happens when the content is piped into `crontab`.

Why the `\n` new line is considered part of the string and don't give a new line effect?

Comment: If you want `echo` to interpret backslash-escape sequences, try replacing `echo` with `echo -e`.

Comment: else use `printf`. Good luck.